# How to perform dynamic filtering of multiple check boxes using cql_filter and openlayers javascript?

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers-2, cql-filter

I have multiple checkboxes for example hospital checkbox where hospital datasets get displayed when checked, phase 1 check box where phase 1 hospitals get displayed when checked and grade A and B check boxes where when A is checked grade A hospital gets displayed. This is a kind of static filter.But I need dynamic filtering. For example, when phase 1 is checked and then grade A is checked I need phase 1 hospitals having grade A to get displayed. Likewise for other flters. Can anyone give suggestion on it using CQL_FILTERING and OpenLayers?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create a [CQL filter](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#cql-filter) that combines the elements that you need to select, so:

```
CQL_FILTER=phase=1 AND grade='A'
```

OpenLayers should take care of URL encoding it for you.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I have a function in which I access check boxes using ID and each for each check box I have a CQL FILTER. Now I need to combine the CQL filters according to the check boxes checked dynamically. Is that possible?

Comment: yes - use AND or OR to combine the cql filters and redraw the layer